# Sphinx custom sorting (FIELD)

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, sphinx

I, have table:

```
id | geo_id | values ....
 1     1      wvrevev
 2     2      wvrevev
 3     3      wvrevev
 3     4      wvrevev
 7     5      wvrevev
 8     6      wvrevev
 9     8      wvrevev
```

In the two fields sphinx indexes: id and geo_id

I need some sort, that would have been at the top of my specified records. In SQL receives such a request:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(geo_id, "2", "3", "6") DESC
```

How do I specify sorting in Sphinx?
This entry:

```
$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "FIELD(geo_id, "2", "3", "6") DESC");
```

Throws an error:

```
enter code hereindex sphinxoffers: sort-by attribute 'field' not found
```

How to get out of the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sphinx doesnt have a FIELD() function
2. You cant specify functions in SORT_EXTENDED mode. there is Sort Expression, but wont help due to 1.

If you always use that list, can just create it as a attribute at indexing time...

```
sql_query = SELECT id, geo_id, FIELD(geo_id, "2", "3", "6") AS sorter, ....
```

then in sphinxAPI code...

```
$cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "sorter DESC");
```

[Edit] or (to add information from the comments)...

> Can build the same logic as FIELD out of nested IF() functions. Can probaly use EXPRESSION sorting, or just create a virtual attribute with SetSelect, and sort by that (using EXTENDED)

---

[Edit2] to use that new attribute, in **sphinxQL**, its just another sorting attribute used in `ORDER BY` (sphinxQL is in effect JUST SPH_SORT_EXTENDED sorting)...

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH(...) ORDER BY sorter DESC, WEIGHT() DESC
```

sort of thing.

Comment: And if I have this attribute is dynamic, something to do with the aid SetSelect is it impossible?

Comment: Its possible, but as there is no FIELD() function have to construct the logic it out of IF() functions.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Sorry that I can not yet put the rating!

Comment: How would I achieve the same using pdo/mysql syntax?